# How to enable access to all origins in Web API with basic authentication enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I want to allow access to all the origins with basic authentication enabled in Web API but whenever I try to call the API through ajax it gives an error stating

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   (CORS issue)

I tried the below mentioned snippet(in webapiconfig).
It worked fine in localhost but after hosting it in IIS it's giving the same error again.

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

I have implemented basic authentication from below link :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/basic-authentication-in-webapi

Also tried commenting the aforementioned snippet and 
adding the below lines in Web.config but this too failed

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization, Content-Type"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

AJAX call :

```
function post()    
{
    var data = {xyz};
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/api/demo',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('abc' + ":" + 'xyz') },
        success: function (response) {    
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (response) { alert('Error'); } 
    });
}
```

I expect that my API should be accessed with credentials irrespective of Origin.

Comment: The call is blocked by the browser and not the API.

Comment: What needs to be done in this case

Comment: did you add AllowAnyOrigin() in your startup.cs ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to disable same origin policy in Chrome.

1.Close Chrome.

2.Open Run.

3.Type chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

and try invoking the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this question, I tried using this command but the browser displays- You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer. I tried running the API but its throwing the same aforementioned error.

Comment: Also it would be better i we could make coding changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes other errors results in `CORS` error. In my case I was struggling with `CORS` error and I already tried everything.

When I tried to monitor incoming requests on server with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) tools I realized that my requests don't hit server at all.

In fact, although `CORS` error made me think error is due to configs on application but it was a firewall issue and whole service was inaccessible. After doing proper configs on firewall `CORS` error gone too